# When should I use the “self” keyword?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, self

When should I be using the `self` expression in my iphone development applications? say i have 2 fields: `UITextField *text1;` and `NSString *str1;` retained and synthesized.

when i am accessing either of these 2 fields, when should i and when should i not use `self.text1` and `self.str1` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are certain circumstances where it's generally discouraged to use the `self.`-expression to access a property. *Normally you* ***always*** *use*  *`self`*  *for any access of a property.* It's the most secure and uncomplicated way. Especially if you used retain, then memory management will be done for you.

The two exceptions from this rule:

- Any `init` method.
- In `dealloc`.

In both cases you are dealing with an *partially initialized* object. There are some side effects that may occur when using setters or getters here -- because they are methods and hence may be overridden.

*For example*, take a class `A` with a property `foo` that has been subclassed by class `B`. The subclass `B` adds an property `bar` and overrode the setter for `foo`. Now your `init`-method calls `setFoo:`, because you used `self.foo = ...` with some initial value. The subclass, however, also accesses the value of `bar` in this setter. But in this case, it may happen that bar has never been initialized and points at some arbitrary data. **Calling a setter in init my cause crashes**, although the probability may not be too high in your own code.

Answer (score 8):

`self` is not a keyword, it is an expression. Additionally, you use it any time you want to refer to a method or property on yourself, or yourself directly. By "yourself" I am of course, referring to the instance of the class you are operating in.

Comment: so it seems like it is identical to the Java `this` expression, which is not always required unless dealing with variables with the same name

Comment: One important difference is that `self.str1 = @"abc"` will use the accessor method (`setStr1:`) but `str1 = @"abc"` will not. When using properties with the `retain` attribute, this difference is critical. So, it's really not "identical to Java `this`".

Answer (score 6):

In your example you aren't directly accessing instance variables when you use `self`, instead you're accessing the properties you've defined.

Consider this example:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
   NSString *_bar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bar;

@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar = _bar;
-(void)baz {
   _bar = @"ivar";  //accessing the ivar
   self.bar = @"property"; //accessing the ivar via the property
}

@end
```

In general if you're using properties, there's little reason to utilize the ivar.  This has the added benefit of automatically retaining & releasing values for you.

But other cases exist when your properties will have a `readonly` modifier.  In these cases it's necessary to directly access your ivars in order to set their values.

Comment: I'm confused.  Where is _foo and foo declared?  Should they really be _bar and bar in your baz method?

Answer (score 5):

It's also a good idea to use `self` within a method call sometimes if you have a custom getter. The `managedContext` object within a Core Data-using application is a good example. If you refer to it by `self.managedContext`, you can override and set the object to what it needs to be if it's `nil`. Refer to the code generated by XCode when creating an application that uses Core Data.

Here is an example of the code generated by XCode, actually:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
@private
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext_;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;



@implementation ContractionTimerAppDelegate

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext_;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext_;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

if you "synthesize" the variable, you should "self." the variable. little rule of thumb

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about objective-c, but this looks a lot like `this` keyword from other languages (like C++, C#, Java, PHP, and others). If so, then my advice is to use it always. That way, if you ever (accidentally) define a local variable with the same name, your code won't break.

However, I must also add, that this is somewhat of a religious debate with a history of flamewars in programmer communities. So take this advice with a grain of salt and use whatever seems to make most sense to you. Just be consistent about it.

Comment: But note that it's not just a style/maintainability issue in objective-C -- when using a property which has getter/setter methods, omitting the "`self`" bypasses the getter/setter; there's a real semantic difference.

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for, nice

Comment: @David Gelhar - sorry. Told you I didn't know. :P