# Objective-C properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

I was just wondering, when accessing properties from within the class, do I have to do `[self someProperty]` or `self.someProperty`? Or is it safe to refer to it simply as `someProperty`?

EDIT: Given that the name of the property doesn't conflict/shawdow....

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to access property with self and when not to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884231/when-to-access-property-with-self-and-when-not-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [self someProperty] or self.someProperty? or can is it safe to refer to it simply as someProperty?

Any one is fine. But I prefer not to use `self` when being in scope of class.

```
someValue = 10 ;
[ self someValue ] = 20 ;
self.someValue = 30 ;
```

All the above three statements are going the modify the interface variable `someValue`.

Comment: Of course, the counterargument to doing it as a simple access rather than a message pass is that it becomes quite a lot of effort to switch the property to atomic or make it some implicit part of your sate. And, for setting, you defeat attempts by third parties to key value observe.

Comment: Is `[ self someValue ] = 20 ;`, perhaps, a typo. I was not aware that this is legal Objective-C.

Comment: the middle one will not modify anything. You need to call a setter to modify the instance variable: `[self setSomeValue:20]`.

Answer (score 2):

Either will work. The `.someProperty` notation is arguably a little safer, as the compiler will throw an error if you make a typo there; by contrast, a mistyped `[self someProperty]` will only generate a warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to refer to the instance variable using just someProperty when reading the value, but when setting the value, if you aren't using [self setSomeProperty:] or self.someProperty =, then there will by no key-value observing messages sent. So if any other object is observing this property, they won't be updated correctly.

This can, occasionally, be what you want by setting the instance variable directly, but usually you want observing to work.