# Another memory management query for ivars

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

There is undoubtedly a wealth of information re: memory management in iOS. Having read a huge amount about it, I am still unclear as to 'BEST' practice for certain situations. Please can I seek clarification on two examples below...

I have an NSMutableArray which is acting as a datasource for a tableView and a UIBarButtonItem called editButton both declared as follows:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController {

   NSMutableArray *datasourceArray;
   UIBarButtonItem *editButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *datasourceArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *editButton;

@end
```

I have then synthesized them and alloc'd/init'd them as follows:

```
@implementation

@syntesize datasourceArray, editButton;

-(void)viewDidLoad {

self.datasourceArray = [self retrieveDatasourceArray];

self.editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editTable)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton, nil] animated:NO];
[editButton release];

}

-(void)retrieveDatasourceArray {

NSMutableArray *datasource = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects @"example1", @"example2", nil] autorelease];

return datasource;

}

-(void)dealloc {

[datasourceArray release];
[editButton release];
[super dealloc];

}
```

**Question 1: The NSMutableArray**

As you can see, I have separated the actual creation of the array into a different method as there is lots of code retrieving from core data and sorting going on (not needed for this question) which I wanted to separate out. I have therefore chosen to return an NSMutableArray which is autoreleased and set this to the self.datasourceArray which is defined in the header file. Is this a sensible and leak free way of implementing this?

**Question 2: The Edit Button**

As I need to change the title and style of the editButton later, I need to have access to it, hence declaring it. I then alloc/init it in the viewDidLoad method and added it to an array (with some other buttons not shown here) before using this array to add the buttons to the navigationBar. I have then released the editButton as I have alloc'd it and handed it to an array. Is this necessary or essential or even in the correct place given my dealloc method?

Many thanks in advance

**EDIT: Further question 3:**

When accessing either of these ivars elsewhere in my code (say when calling [datasourceArray count] or resetting the title of the 'Edit' button to 'Done', should I use self. notation or not?

**EDIT: Further question 4:**

Elsewhere I have used the following code to initialise a synthesised NSMutableArray. Given the below answers, is this more leaky...?

```
[self setDatasourceArray: [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self retrieveDatasourceArray]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st point for the Array**

```
NSMutableArray *datasource = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects @"example1", @"example2", nil] autorelease];

return datasource;
```

here you are doing it **correct**..returning an **autoreleased** object..which will be retained by the variable because you defined it to be of type retain (when you did `@property`).

**2nd point for the edit button**

```
self.editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editTable)];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton, nil] animated:NO];

[editButton release];
```

Here you are apparently **over releasing** the object..
remember the variable retains the new variable you defined..so edit button retains the  new bar button item..so releasing it . is necessary one time..which you do in dealloc..but releasing here also will lead to overrelease..to solve this just remove the release line and update your code to be like this

```
self.editButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editTable)]autorelease];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton, nil] animated:NO];
```

Here you see that the new instance which will be created will be auto released..and its value will be retained by your variable

Comment: excellent thanks - much appreciated. Could I possibly trouble you to look at question 3 which I have just added? The reason I have added it because of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080523/when-should-i-use-the-self-keyword in which someone says you should use init when using self. notation. Any thoughts?

Comment: self.iVarName should be used when you haves defined the variable a @property and init and autorelease are simply the way of alternative to not use init...if you don't use init..that abject is autorelesased...and when you use init..you should use autorelease too so that it becomes autorealease object again..

Comment: I have added two more questions. If you have time to answer that would be very helpful.